# Does the mov instruction move data from register to memory

Tags: assembly, masm, cpu-registers, x86-16

I wanted to know if when you use the `mov` instruction from register to memory in a loop, does it overwrite what is already in the memory location each time or does it just add to it?

For example, if the `al` register contains '2', and you move it to a memory location and then you do it again but this time `al` register contains '9', does the memory location now contain '9' or '29'.

Comment: The MOV instruction overwrites the destination.

Comment: how could you add to it, in the same way that cld     ;clear direction flag
mov esi, OFFSET string1 
mov edi, OFFSET string2 
Mov ecx, 10   
rep movsb

Comment: That code doesn't add to anything. It overwrites the 10 bytes at the destination, replacing them with the 10 bytes at the source.

Comment: the add instruction is for adding, the mov instruction is for moves or copies the value across.

Comment: Of course the data will be `'9'`, but what do you mean by `'29'`? Wouldn't it be `'k'` (assuming ASCII code is used) or `'11'` (assuming the quotation is just for readability and not used as it is used in C code) if addition were performed?

Comment: The result may be something called '29' if the "memory" written is actually a memory-mapped I/O port.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with inline assembly using Dev C++ running someone's code. Two solutions seemed to work - either define the memory location as 1-byte long (int8_t) and compare (if needed) and move 1 byte, or define the output as being in memory not in a register. (=m) not (=r).

Comment: I think you're answering a different question.  This one isn't about (GNU C) inline `asm` in C or C++, it's about what `mov` means in regular asm.  (And seems to maybe be talking about appending to strings, not integer addition, which makes no sense because a single byte as the destination for `mov` can only hold one ASCII character.)